# Finding latex class name using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to use python regex to find the document class in a latex document.

A latex file contains `\documentclass{myclass}` somewhere near the top. I want to find `myclass` using regex.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
latex_text = "blank  /documentclass{myclass} words, more text /documentclassdoc{11} more words"
s=re.search(r'/documentclass{(?P<class_name>.*)}', latex_text)
```

It matches: `myclass} words, more text /documentclassdoc{11`

How can I change it to only match `myclass`. It should also stop searching after it finds a match, as the document can get quite long.

I know the file should only have one documentclass, but I want to handle the case where there is more than 1 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
latex_text = "blank  /documentclass{myclass} words, more text /documentclassdoc{11} more words"
print(re.search(r'/documentclass\{(.*?)\}', latex_text).group())
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed it slightly to get the class name: `print(re.search(r'/documentclass\{(?P<class_name>.*?)\}', latex_text).group('class_name'))`

Comment: If you plan to do more heavy-handed manipulation or searches in the future, TexSoup is an option; just wanted to throw that hat into the ring. https://github.com/alvinwan/texsoup. Here, we could do `soup = TexSoup(r"blank  \documentclass{myclass} words,..."); soup.documentclass.name`. Disclaimer: I wrote TexSoup but it was for slightly more tasks and thought it might be useful.